# many to many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have a model below that represents the situation:

- Students participate in Contests.
- Contests measure certain skills.
- For each contest, each student gets a score for each skill measured.

Here are my models:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  attr_accessible :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :skills
  has_many :contest_participations
  has_many :contests, :through => :contest_participations
  has_many :contest_scores, :through => :contests

end

class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :students
end

class Contest < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :contest_participations_attributes, :contest_scores_attributes
  has_many :contest_participations
  has_many :students, :through => :contest_participations
  has_many :contest_skills
  has_many :skills, :through => :contest_skills
  has_many :contest_scores
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contest_participations, :contest_scores


end

class ContestParticipation < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :contest_id, :student_id
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :contest
end

class ContestScore < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :contest_id, :score, :skill_id, :student_id
  has_and_belongs_to_many :contests
  has_and_belongs_to_many :skills
  has_and_belongs_to_many :student
end
```

In my contests edit view, I'm trying to create a form, with formtastic, that will show all contest participants, and allow the user to add a score for each skill in the contest as follows.

But I get an error (student_id invalid symbol). How can I update the student scores?

```
<%= semantic_form_for @contest do |f| %>

    <%= f.input :name %>

    <%= @contest.students.each do |student| %>
         <%= @contest.skills.each do |skill| %>
               <%= f.inputs :name => "Scores", :for => :contest_scores do |scores_form| %>
                     <%= scores_form.input :student_id => "student.id" %>
                     <%= scores_form.input :skill_id => "skill.id" %>
                     <%= scores_form.input :score, :label => "Score" %>
               <% end %>
               <br />                 
         <% end %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.actions do %>
         <%= f.action :submit, :as => :button %>
    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Do you get a similar error if you swap the `:student_id` and `:skill_id` input fields (except the error would be on the `:skill_id` input instead?

Comment: @normalocity - if I swap the error is on `skill_id`. Thanks.

Comment: The error only happens if I assign `:student_id => "student.id"`. If I don't assign, the form works without errors. But I want to assign the student and skill automatically and only have the user input score.

Comment: What if you remove the quotes, e.g.: `scores_form.input :student_id => student.id`

Comment: @normalocity - without quotes, error `{:student_id=>1} is not a symbol` - thanks

Comment: Assigning student.name to form label works fine - `<%= scores_form.input :student_id, :label => student.name  %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Added hidden because e think you don't want ids to show up

```
<%= scores_form.input :student_id, :as => :hidden, :value => student.id %>
<%= scores_form.input :skill_id, :as => :hidden, :value => skill.id %>
```

Comment: don't forget to accept this and the other answer on your other question please